# inflector - whats the cakephp plural of feedback?

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I want to have a table for feedback in my cakephp app but I can't figure out what I should call it.

What is the plural of feedback that cakephp will understand?

Thanks - Sarah

Comment: feedbacks is plural feedback

Comment: Always You can tested on: http://inflector.cakephp.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this in a view and find out :)

`echo Inflector::pluralize( "feedback" );`

If you don't like what the plural is you can change it in your `bootstrap.php` file. Open it and look for `Inflector::rules()`

See [Inflector documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#inflection-configuration) for how the rules work.

Comment: thanks llie... the answer is feedbacks. Which isn't real English but there you are!

Comment: updated answer to include how to configure the Inflector. (ah.. Dave beat me to it!)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set the plural of feedback to feedback, you can do:

```
Inflector::rules('plural', array('irregular' => array('feedback' => 'feedback')));
```

in your app/config/bootstrap.php file:

Comment: Or simply `public $uses = array('Feedback')`